# select2 change selection programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I've got a select2 selection that I'm trying to set the value for using javascript.
I've created a fiddle at this address. 
https://jsfiddle.net/rfeynman/wn9v3bud/

I'm trying both he following

```
// method 1
$('#groupList').select2('data',{id:"group2", text:"group2"},true);

// method 2: as seen on the select2 website
var groupList = $('#groupList').select2();
$(groupList).val("group2").trigger("change");
```

My problem is that I'm unable to change the selection for a select2 input that loads data using ajax. Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

looks like this can be done using the following code. you need to add the option to the select list and then set the value.

```
var option=$("<option>").attr("value","group2").html("group2");
$("#groupList").append(option);
$("#groupList").val("group2").trigger("change");
```

Comment: There is another way, you can do `$("#groupList").select2().select2('val', value);` This usually works but not working in your case. This might be because of use of `data` attribute